# OpenSkyApi: array of string or list of string?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, api

I'm using OpenSkyApi (Documentation [here](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/index.html)).

I want to use the function

```
get_states(time_secs=0, icao24=None, serials=None)
```

On the docs you can see that:

> Returns:  OpenSkyStates if request was successful, None otherwise

This is my code that actually does't work (The fuction returns None)

```
def get_flights():
  s = api.get_states()
  flights = []
  j = 0
  # I want just 5 best results of the first 10 elements returned with **api.get_states()**
  for i in range(10):
          tmp = s.states[i]
          if tmp.icao24 != "" and tmp.latitude != "" and tmp.longitude != "" and j < 5:
              flights.append(tmp.icao24)
              j += 1
  return flights

flights = get_flights()
s = api.get_states(icao24=flights)
```

and actually this code works

```
flights = ['43ea96', 'aa8477', 'aa56da', 'a3e917', 'a52911']
s = api.get_states(icao24=flights)

print(s)
```

How can i pass that array of strings dinamically?

P.s. The function is basically a REST API that returns a JSON object (e.g.):

```
{'altitude': 8001,
'callsign': 'FDX1162 ',
'heading': 317.58,
'icao24': 'a8f9f2',
'latitude': 39.1745,
'longitude': -103.8766,
'on_ground': False,
'origin_country': 'United States',
'sensors': None,
'time_position': 1480590928,
'time_velocity': 1480590928,
'velocity': 226.49,
'vertical_rate': -13}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ***fixje***, a collaborator of Open Sky Network Project, i fixed my issue. 
He told me that:

> The API will also return None if you exceed the rate limit as given in
>   the following table.
>
> [image]
>
> In the first code snippet you issue two consecutive requests within a
>   very short time, so the second one,
>
> ```
> api.get_states(icao24=flights)
> ```
>
> will return *None*.